# List strings not found in files with grep

Tags: grep

I have a directory of images `Images/` and a load of `.tex` files in the same directory. I want to work out if any of the images in `Images/` aren't used in the tex files.

So far I've found you can pass a list of the strings you want to grep using `-f`, so I put all the images into a list and I've found you can count the number of occurrences of strings using `grep -c`. But this gives me a list of the `.tex` files with the number of images in each of them:

```
Tex1.tex:0
Tex2.tex:21
...
```

How can I have a list of occurrences of the images? A list of images which are never used would be ideal!
What I'd like is:

```
Image1.pdf:0
Image2.png:21
...
```